# Issue Updating Grails Domain Class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am having an issue with a simple update of a Grails Domain class and I really need a sanity check.  My domain class is

```
class Container implements Serializable{

String barcode
Float tare
static hasOne = [containerContent:ContainerContent, containerSolvent:ContainerSolvent]

static constraints = {
    barcode blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true, size: 0..100
    containerSolvent blank: true, nullable: true, unique: true
    containerContent blank: true, nullable: true, unique: true
    tare blank: true, nullable: true
}}
```

When I try to update the Containers property "tare" in the following manner I am getting an error (below)

```
myFoundContainer = Container.findByBarcode(contents.get("barcode"))
def myContainer = Container.get(myFoundContainer.id )
def myTare = contents.get("tare")

try{
              myContainer.lock()
              myContainer.tare = myTare
              myContainer.save(flush:true)
    }
catch (org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
               println(e)
    }
```

I then get the error:

**No value specified for parameter 1**  java.sql.SQLException

Which I assume refers to the Container id in the constructor? But I did not think this would matter during an update.

In the console I also see the following message:

**Hibernate: select id from container where id =? and version =? for update**

One thought, does this have to do with any of the constraints "hasOne"

I am using a MySQL database if that helps.  Thank you for any assistance.

```
  No value specified for parameter 1. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No value specified for parameter 1
    Line | Method
->> 1074 | createSQLException    in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    988 | createSQLException    in     ''
|    974 | createSQLException .  in     ''
|    919 | createSQLException    in     ''
|   2611 | checkAllParametersSet in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
|   2586 | fillSendPacket        in     ''
|   2510 | fillSendPacket . . .  in     ''
|   2259 | executeQuery          in     ''
|     96 | executeQuery . . . .  in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement
|    358 | uploadMethod          in com.sagerx.UpdateContainerStatusUponReceiptService$$EOHFXFJX
|     24 | uploadFile . . . . .  in com.sagerx.UpdateContainerStatusController
|    195 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                   in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Add `myTare` and `myFoundContainer` to the question as well.

Comment: I import these values (tare and barcode) from a spreadsheet into a map, I can confirm that they are not null

Comment: You already have the container, why are you doing `get` on it again. Isn't `myFoundContainer` same as `myContainer`?

Comment: Yeah, I added that in when I thought perhaps there was something funny going on with "findByBarcode"

Comment: Full stacktrace will be helpful now.

Comment: added the stack above, thank you for your help

Comment: You have an answer, verify if that is the case. Which version of grails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be related to this [Grails JIRA Issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8101) (also mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447922/how-to-cope-with-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-no-value-specified-for-para))

This issue mentions a similar error which occurs when using the `unique: true` constraint on  a one-to-one association. Try removing the unique constraint from `containerSolvent` and `containerContent`

Comment: thanks, trying this now...I was wondering if this may be part of the issue

Comment: That did it, I would give you a Point if I had more rep!!  Thanks a million, this was really frustrating

Comment: Great to hear it helped. You should probably vote for this Grails Jira issue